# Install VMware workstation 7 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vmware, installation

when I run the installer on my Windows 7 machine, I get the error:

```
bootstrap.lua was not found.
```

It works on Windows Vista.
Any ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 4):

You may have a corrupt copy, I would recommend re [downloading it direct from VMware](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/workstation_7_0_for_windows/ZGolYmQlJSViZGVkZQ==).

I am using VMWare Workstation on Windows 7 without problems and have installed it a few times and never seen the error you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Regards "bootstrap.lua" not found
I had same Problem, but it worked after i download again the same
software (same date same version) via Downloadmanager directly from the VMWare Webpage.
So maybe first time i just got an invalid copy

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in Vista compatibility mode if it worked on Vista. Make sure you're also running the installer as administrator as it needs a higher level of access to install the components.

Comment: I already have tried both, but it won´t work.

Comment: That's fairly odd. I have it running on my 7 box, possibly some previously installed software is conflicting with it? Maybe something is wrong with the download?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should, from an administrator account :

1. uninstall VMWare Workstation and reboot
2. download it again
3. turn UAC off, as well as all antivirus and firewall products
4. reinstall and reboot
5. turn back on everything from step 3
6. reboot